# Custom Formula Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to change format of cell A1 colored green , depends on the value in cells (A2:A5) if all cells value is "Done" , I want to color A1 Green.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Approach:

Now you are checking only the cell `A2`. You should check all the column range.

Your idea is to make your header green when all the cells contain the word "Done". You can translate this idea to: I have exactly 0 cells that don't contain the word "Done". This way you won't have to keep track of how many cells are in your column.

You can count how many values respect a criterion using the function `COUNTIF`.

### Formula:

`=COUNTIF(A2:A5, "<>Done") = 0`